# Can any data-structure data be converted to json format?

Tags: json, serialization, data-structures, type-conversion

I am mainly curious to know if complex data types like trees, graphs, map or other more complex data types can be converted to json format with same flexibility of serialization as lightweight objects.

Considering json format is simply a Key/Value format for text interchange, (field/value or name/value - whichever you like. where value could be one or many and value could be simple type or another json type),

Would it be necessary for any data structure to satisfy this condition?

- **Can a single object of the data structure be represented using key-value or key-[array] structure?**

**Yes** - then this is good for json format;

*No* -  then break down this data structure to smaller key-value structure! or what can be done?

Please break down your answer into fine details!

I am just doing some research around json and various data structure and would greatly appreciate various opinion around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generaly you can do nearly everything up to `tree` complexity. You cannot directly represent things like `graphs` (even `graphs without cycles`) but there are ways to overcome this limits.

- Vectors and lists can be represented as arrays,
- Trees as arrays of arrays.

Problem arisies here, with graph, or just a single reference to arbitrary object in your JSON.

```
+- Root Object -------------+
|   +-------+   +-------+   |
|   | OBJ_A |   | OBJ_B |   |
|   +-------+   +-------+   |
|   | ref------>|       |   |
|   +-------+   +-------+   |
|    field_a     field_b    |
+---------------------------+
```

You can overcome such limitations in many ways:

- If these 2 objects are in same array, instead of reference you can strore key/index
- More general way is to store all objects in separate array, and instead of references store indices to this array
- Another way is to name every object uniquely, and store their names in place of references

All above solutions unfortunately require postprocessing to convert pseudo-references (indices/names/etc) into real 'native' references.

Comment: so basically, data structures with cyclic reference is not good candidate for json format that's what you mean?

Comment: Yes any cyclic graph or even any graph which is not a tree is not a good candidate. For such things you'd need another serialization language like xml.

Comment: i am still waiting for more feedback from various experts